# How to add some feature to existing SMS Message application in android

Tags: android, sms

I want to use the existing sms application in android phones and add some features.

How to use them.i want the entire functionality including interface, logging as thread etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although its about a different built in app, this is essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764918/android-modify-the-source-code-of-contacts-application/6765363#6765363 - the answer I provided there would be equally applicable here.

Comment: @chris Stratton: Thank u i just saw tht previous post u linked.i dont want to modify the sms application.i just want ot use them in a new app.Is there any API to access them ?

Comment: I want to add some plug-ins for native sms application in android.i must be able to copy them into my own application and add some features.Is that possible

Comment: The built-in SMS application does not support 'plug ins' so you will have to either modify and re-install it, or create a replacement perhaps using some of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do here:

Simple way:

```
SmsManager mgr = SmsManager.getDefault();    
String phoneNumber = "12345667860";    
mgr.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "Sup bbz", null, null);
```

Alternate way using intents:

```
String phoneNumber = "12345667860";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", phoneNumber, null)));
```

Android uses intents to communicate between processes in the dvm.

Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) to know more about the exposed api

Comment: I want to add some plug-ins for native sms application in android.i must be able to copy them into my own application and add some features.Is that possible.

Comment: What kind of features? You can only launch the sms editor from your app. I highly suggest you read a book on android.